# ssh-keyscan -H returns different keys every time

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm getting different keys every time I run `ssh-keyscan -H some.hostname.example`. Why is that? Is the server continuously changing keys?

They keys I'm getting from one run seems to work even after a subsequent run, because I'm not getting any warnings when I `ssh` into the server, even though I've saved one set of keys to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Edit: I was wrong, the keys do not change, however the first column (with the host name) changes. It's on the form `|1|<something base64>|<something else base64>`. I'm not quite sure what's encoded in base64, but it appears to be binary.

Comment: Can we get 2 output exaples?

Comment: I just realized that the keys stay the same, but the first column (with host name) changes. The host is written on the form `|1|<something in base64>|<something else in base64>`.

Comment: Does the IP address change as well? :) (I'm thinking of round-robin DNS)

Answer (score 1):

The hostname-part is hashed. the same name/ip might have different hashes (remember, you used ssh-keycheck -H). So this is normal behavior.

Comment: You sure about that? Normally multiple values can hash to the same result, but a hash function would be pointless if it gave different results for the same input. That would make hashing passwords completely useless, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56268/ssh-benefits-of-using-hashed-known-hosts explains in detail how the hashing is done.

The gist of it is that it includes a "salt" (random additional data), to not have the same hash and make it easy to precompute the hashes for a lot of input texts. The salt is random, but shown, not hashed itself.